# Django Apscheduler: Error getting due jobs from job store 'default': connection already closed

Tags: python, django, apscheduler

I have configured django-apscheduler in my django project. I am getting error of gettig due job store. I used these configuration in my settings.py file.

```
SCHEDULER_CONFIG = {
    "apscheduler.jobstores.default": {
        "class": "django_apscheduler.jobstores:DjangoJobStore"
    },
    'apscheduler.executors.processpool': {
        "type": "threadpool"
    }
}
SCHEDULER_AUTOSTART = True
```

Also I have created a scheduler.py file parallel to settings.py with these code lines.

```
import logging

from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
from django.conf import settings

scheduler = BackgroundScheduler(settings.SCHEDULER_CONFIG,job_defaults={'misfire_grace_time': 15*60},deamon=True)


def createJob(func, params, tz, id, hour='*', minute='*', ):
    scheduler.add_job(func, 'cron', params, hour=hour, minute=minute, timezone=tz, id=id)


def printJob():
    try:
        scheduler.print_jobs()
    except Exception as e:
        pass


def removeJob(id):
    try:
        scheduler.remove_job(id)
    except Exception as e:
        pass


def start():
    if settings.DEBUG:
        logging.basicConfig()
        logging.getLogger('apscheduler').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    scheduler.start()


start()
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to your problem here? I just started having the same issue today and haven't been able to make any progress on it. I've got almost the exact same project setup.

Comment: I am still looking into it. I did'nt found a solution to it.

Comment: I managed to isolate mine to production only, which for me is a single docker container running on azure app services and connected to a managed pg database, also on azure. Running the same app locally against the same database never produces the issue (though i am running it in debug mode), so maybe our issue is in with our web-server setups? They'd be one of the few things that change between dev and production.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yeah you are right I will try to run in production with same db.

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered the same error. The problem was that the **function called by the scheduler was local**, and was defined in another function that initialized it into the scheduler.

```
def function_scheduler_init(scheduler: ContextScheduelerDecorator):
   
   def function_i_want_call_here():
        pass

   scheduler.add_job(function_i_want_call_here, **kwargs)
```

Solution: make the function global

```
def function_i_want_call_here():
    pass

def function_scheduler_init(scheduler: ContextScheduelerDecorator):
   
   scheduler.add_job(function_i_want_call_here, **kwargs)
```